# z-index:-1 hiding the content after fa icon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, z-index

`z-index:-1` hiding the content after fa icon.

I want to hide the line under the **check icon**

[image]

What I have currently:

```css
.application-intro a {
  color: inherit !important;
}

.application-intro .step-icons {
  color: #4c5280;
  font-size: 4rem;
  /* width: 80px; */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
  /* width: 20px; */
}

.application-intro ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.application-intro ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.application-intro .progress-icon {
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  /* width: 80px; */
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.application-intro .progress-icon::after {
  content: '';
  background: #ccc;
  height: 5px;
  width: 110%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  /* top: 125px; */
  top: 103px;
}

.application-intro span {
  width: 30%;
  display: table;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  margin-left: 36%;
}

.application-intro li:nth-child(2) .progress-icon {
  color: #148e14;
}

.application-intro li:nth-child(2) .progress-icon::after {
  background: #148e14;
}

.application-intro li:first-child .progress-icon::after {
  width: 95%;
  left: 52%;
}

.application-intro li:last-child .progress-icon::after {
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="application-intro">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn" id="fill-application" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-pen step-icons"></i></a><br><i class="fas fa-circle-check progress-icon"></i><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span></li>
    <li><a class="btn" id="submit-kyc" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-arrow-up step-icons"></i></a><br><i class="fas fa-circle-check progress-icon"></i><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span></li>
    <li><a class="btn" id="match-financial" href=""><i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass step-icons"></i></a><br><i class="fas fa-circle-check progress-icon"></i><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JasperEl/ec95zg7n/5/

A negative value on the z-index not working here. I'm looking forward to a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use background clip by `content-box` (round it with `border-radius:50%`), then return z-index. Some subpixel outline may occur.

```css
.application-intro a {
  color: inherit !important;
}

.application-intro .step-icons {
  color: #4c5280;
  font-size: 4rem;
  /* width: 80px; */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
  /* width: 20px; */
}

.application-intro ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.application-intro ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.application-intro .progress-icon {
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  /* width: 80px; */
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.application-intro .progress-icon::after {
  content: '';
  background: #ccc;
  height: 5px;
  width: 110%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /*add z-index*/
  z-index: -1;
  /* top: 125px; */
  top: 103px;
}

.application-intro span {
  width: 30%;
  display: table;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  margin-left: 36%;
}

.application-intro li:nth-child(2) .progress-icon {
  color: #148e14;
  /* add some background and cip it by content box*/
  background-clip: content-box;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.application-intro li:nth-child(2) .progress-icon::after {
  background: #148e14;
  
}

.application-intro li:first-child .progress-icon::after {
  width: 95%;
  left: 52%;
}

.application-intro li:last-child .progress-icon::after {
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="application-intro">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn" id="fill-application" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-pen step-icons"></i></a><br><i class="fas fa-circle-check progress-icon"></i><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span></li>
    <li><a class="btn" id="submit-kyc" href=""><i class="fas fa-file-arrow-up step-icons"></i></a><br><i class="fas fa-circle-check progress-icon"></i><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span></li>
    <li><a class="btn" id="match-financial" href=""><i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass step-icons"></i></a><br><i class="fas fa-circle-check progress-icon"></i><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But a better solution would be build that graphics with separate elements for the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use position `relative` and `z-index 1` for your `.fa-circle-check::before` Element.
But you should choese another content to it, because your content is transparent in the middle and your `after` Element picks out of the transparent area of your `before` Element.
Just change the color of one of your elements after applying the positioning, so you can See what I mean.

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: Use the method from @Vladimir then :)